# Brick Breaker Ball Bounce

Tags: c++, sdl, collision, breakout

I'm trying to make my own Brick Breaker game using SDL library and I'm having some issues with dealing the collision resolution and ball bouncing when it comes to the bouncing of the paddle.

I'm calculating collision angle based on the collision point between ball and paddle and calculating balls' velocity direction based on that angle.

The issue I'm experiencing is after the collision with the paddle, ball doesn't change it's Y direction, instead just keeps going down and hitting the paddle. It continues to do that until eventually "slides" of the paddle.

I don't think my math is wrong here (although it could easily be), but I simply don't know what the issue is or how to fix it.

This is the code that is responsible for collision detection and calculating angle and direction.

```
void Ball::CollisionWithPaddle(Paddle*& paddle)
{
    if (CollisionManager::GetInstance()->Collision(GetHitbox(), paddle->GetHitbox()))
    {   
        double collisionAngle = CalculateCollisionAngle(paddle->GetHitbox());
        
        Vector2Df newVelocityDirection = CalculateNewVelocityDirection(collisionAngle);  
        velocity = newVelocityDirection * velocity.Magnitude();             

        AdjustBallPosition(paddle);
    }   
}

double Ball::CalculateCollisionAngle(const SDL_Rect& paddle)
{
    double collisionPointX = transform->X + width / static_cast<double>(2);
    double collisionPointY = transform->Y + height / static_cast<double>(2);

    double relativeX = collisionPointX - (paddle.x + paddle.w / static_cast<double>(2));
    double relativeY = collisionPointY - (paddle.y + paddle.h / static_cast<double>(2));

    double collisionAngle = atan2(relativeY, relativeX);

    return collisionAngle;
}

Vector2Df Ball::CalculateNewVelocityDirection(double collisionAngle)
{
    // Calculate direction of the new velocity based on the collision angle
    double newVelocityX = std::cos(collisionAngle);
    double newVelocityY = -std::sin(collisionAngle);

    Vector2Df newVelocityDirection(newVelocityX, newVelocityY);
    
    return newVelocityDirection.Normalize();
}

void Ball::AdjustBallPosition(Paddle* paddle)
{
    transform->Y = paddle->GetHitbox().y - height;  
}
```

This is the code where I'm simply updating the position of the ball with the current velocity.

```
void Ball::Update()
{
    transform->X += velocity.X * Engine::GetInstance()->GetDeltaTime();
    transform->Y += velocity.Y * Engine::GetInstance()->GetDeltaTime();

    rec.x = transform->X;
    rec.y = transform->Y;   
}
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing degrees and radians.

Comment: @Bert i don't really follow what you're saying.. should i be doing something differently

Comment: Assuming you programmed the above, I'd expect you to know the difference between radians and degree and that the C++ trigonometric functions use radians (e.g., https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2) but you treat it like degrees (`fmod((collisionAngle + 180), 360) - 180`).

Comment: @Bert i did notice that i made a mistake there but it was a part of experimenting, my question was suppose to be without it... so just pretend the line doesn't exist and my question is still the same

Comment: I suggest to write a test for the code independent of your application (a unit test). In this test, you set the initial conditions, determine the expected outcome and run the test. The amount of code involved is pretty limited, so stepping through it with a debugger or outputting the values at each step should be straight forward and quickly tells you where your code veers off your expectation.

Comment: i will try to do that, but is there smth im missing or the logic behind this is not correct?